# Combined adjoint and natural representation

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

I am a physicist and am looking for some guidance with what mathematical structures I am dealing.

I have some physical states that can be uniquely represented by products of 4x4-matrices. There are two sets of matrices, say $(1,A_1,A_2,A_3)$ and $(1,X_1,X_2,X_3)$ (where $1$ is the identity). Each state of my system may be written as some linear combination
\begin{equation}
   \psi = \sum_{i,j=0} a_i A_i X_j,
\end{equation}
where the $a_i$ are some real numbers.

I can connect the states of my system by transformations that all look like $\psi \to h g \psi g^{-1}$, where $h$ and $g$ are group elements (which represent lattice symmetry group operations) that can be written as linear combinations of $1,A_i$ and $1,X_i$, respectively.

It appears like my object transforms both in a adjoint and a fundamental representation of my symmetry group (are those even defined for discrete groups)? Is there any name for this kind of mathematical structure?

**Update:**
More generally, is there a specific term for groups with some operation $\odot$ whose Elements also span a vector space with an operation $\oplus$? Like invertible matrices usually do?

Comment: The set of all matrices does not form a group. The set of all *invertible* matrices forms a group.

Comment: @Nick, thanks, corrected this.

Comment: Also, the set $\mathrm{GL}_n$ of invertible matrices is not a vector space, since the sum of two invertible matrices may not be invertible. Or do you maybe mean something more like the group algebra of $\mathrm{GL}_n$, where the basis vectors correspond to elements of the group?